# How can I create a snmp trap handlers using c#?

Tags: c#, snmp

How can I create snmp trap handlers using c# for receiving info from the UPS 
which is connected directly to the LAN network with its own IP address?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start from SNMP protocol to create your own, or utilize existing libraries,

http://www.lextm.com/2007/12/product-review-snmp-libraries-for-net.html

To be biased, I recommend my own open source project #SNMP, where you can find how to capture traps (snmptrapd.exe sample in source code package), and then you can easily handle them.

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com

Comment: Actually i tried your library [Ver : 0.7.8.0], first before posting here.
But i get error while making SNMP request.

       Line : SnmpV1Packet result = (SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);      Error :   Request has reached maximum retries.

Comment: I am new to SNMP and trying to fetch the status of UPS. Help me on this..Thanks.

Comment: I have a SOCOMEC UPS, which sends a message when there is a Power Fail. I want to fetch that in my c# application. I also have the MIB file of that UPS. Kindly guide me on this... Thanks..

Comment: #SNMP never has a 0.7.8.0 release so you must not use any of "my library". Make sure you describe your problem correctly.